# Redirecting to an external domain in Flask

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm writing a very simple flask app (a URL shortener) that should be able to redirect certain requests to other arbitrary domains. However, I am running into problems with the redirection. This stripped-down version, for example, doesn't work:

```
from app import app, db
from flask import abort, redirect

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, world"

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    abort(404)

@app.route('/<slug>')
def redirect(slug):
    return redirect('http://google.com/')
```

Perhaps naively, I expected this to redirect to google.com, but instead the redirect seems to get "captured" by Flask, and it tries to route the redirected URL back through the redirect handler (e.g. `redirect(slug="http://google.com/")`) until it eats all the stack space through recursion and errors out. I can't  seem to figure out why this would happen, or how to work around it, but I'd really appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this function:

```
@app.route('/<slug>')
def redirect(slug):
    return redirect('http://google.com/')
```

You named the function `redirect()`, so in the scope of the function when you call `return redirect(...)` this is interpreted as a recursive call because the view function shadows Flask's function of the same name. And the URL that you pass is mapped to the `slug` argument in the recursive call.

Change the name of the view function from `redirect()` to something else and your code will work just fine.

Comment: @Miguel thank you i also make same mistake, stupid! just wasted 1 hour on this.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you! 6 years later, reply saved me from this uncomprehendably stupid problem..